# Repository still big after migrating to LFS

Tags: git, git-lfs

I'm working with Unreal Engine 4 and it serializes all its asset files as binary files. Currently, the project size is less than 10MB but the .git folder is almost 700MB.
I have LFS tracked all asset files and did an `lfs migrate` on the repo, but the repo is still big. GitHub says files are in LFS but I didn't see my LFS storage usage meter go up after pushing the rewritten history.

I'm not sure if this is the way LFS works but as I understand it Git will store a pointer to the file in LFS and only download the version of the file from the commit your HEAD is at.

I'm pretty lost here. I think it's worth mentioning I'm kind of a newb in git so please go easy on me.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I ran `git lfs install --skip-smudge` and then cloned the repo, this made the repo folder a lot smaller since no LFS files were downloaded when cloning. The problem is that now I only have the pointer files and doing a `git lfs pull` fails to check out all files. Error message is `Could not check out "<file-name>"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git LFS will keep the versions of the files in *recent* commits. Here, 'recent' means the value of `lfs.fetchrecentrefsdays` configuration property. So LFS will pull all versions that are 7 days or newer (this is the default value, but you can change it).

To remove all *old* files you need to `git lfs prune`. A prune will remove all file versions that are older than `lfs.fetchrecentrefsdays` + `lfs.pruneoffsetdays`. `lfs.pruneoffsetdays` defaults to 3 and `lfs.fetchrecentrefsdays` defaults to 7 so when a prune is run all versions older than 10 days will be removed.

More info [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs?_ga=2.266014156.236507635.1541440465-1684781032.1540314308#fetching-history)

**EDIT:** as for the "Could not checkout file" error I was getting, a clean install of Git did the trick.